# SharePoint 2010 - Display Frontend Server IP on SharePoint Site?

Tags: 2010

It is possible to display the Frontend Server IP dynamically on a SharePoint Site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I normally add this to the master page, with a control that spits out `Environment.MachineName`, or just use `<%=Environment.MachineName%>`.

Update: I think the machine name is better, since a machine can have several IP's on different NIC's.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! great idea! But it is possible to use this command without editing the Masterpage?

Comment: You need to edit (or add a custom) the master page to get it to be displayed on all sites/pages.